# I wonder if there are a lot of collections

Tags: mongodb

Do many mongodb collections have a big impact on mongodb performance, memory and capacity? I am designing an api with mvc pattern, and a collection is being created for each model. I question the way I am doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MongoDB with the WirdeTiger engine supports an unlimited number of collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/). So you are not going to run into any hard technical limitations.

When you wonder if something should be in one collection or in multiple collections, these are some of the considerations you need to keep in mind:

- More collections = more maintenance work. Sharding is configured on the collection level. So having a large number of collections will make shard configuration a lot more work. You also need to set up indexes for each collection separately, but this is quite easy to automatize, because `createIndex` on an index which already exists does nothing.
- The MongoDB API is designed in a way that every database query operates on one collection at a time. That means when you need to search for a document in `n` different collections, you need to perform `n` queries. When you need to aggregate data stored in multiple collections, you run into even more problems. So any data which is queried together should be stored together in the same collection.

Creating one collection for each class in your model is *usually* a god rule of thumb, but it is not a golden hammer solution. There are situations where you want to embed object in their parent-object documents instead of putting them into a separate collection. There are also cases where you want to put all objects with the same base-class in the same collection to benefit from MongoDB's ability to handle heterogeneous collections. But that goes beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this and test your application ?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/evaluate-operation-performance/

By the way your question is not completely clear... is more like a "discussion" rather than question. And you're asking others to evaluate your work instead of searching the web the rigth approach.